# While loop ending too quickly

Tags: c

I'm working to create a program with the following output with inputs (2.0) and (3.0):

Concentration of ammonia after 0.38s = 1.729 mol/L

3.39s required for rate to drop below 0.040 mol/(L*s)

Concentration of nitrogen gas after 3.39s = 0.603 mol/L

Average concentration of water after 3.39s = 1.148 mol/L

Reaction has passed 50% completion

However, my while loop does not iterate that far for some reason. Here is the code I am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    //Define value of k, starting concentration of NH3,starting concentration of O2,current concentration of NH3,current concentration of O2, current concentration of N2, current concentration of water, waterProduced, reactionRate and time as floats; initialize k and time, since k is a constant and t has a fixed starting time
    float ammoniaStart,oxygenStart,ammoniaCurrent,oxygenCurrent,nitrogenCurrent, waterCurrent, waterProduced,reactionRate;
    float k = 1.14*pow(10,-2);
    printf("k = %f\n",k);
    float time = 0.38;
    //Define int i: used as an iterator
    int i = 0;
    //Scan in the starting concentrations of O2 and NH3
    printf("Enter initial ammonia & oxygen concentrations:");
    scanf("%f %f",&ammoniaStart,&oxygenStart);
    ammoniaCurrent = ammoniaStart;
    oxygenCurrent = oxygenStart;
    printf("ammoniaCurrent = %f, oxygenCurrent = %f\n",ammoniaCurrent,oxygenCurrent);
    //While loop: while the concentration of NH3 is greater than the starting concentration of NH3 / 2 OR while the concentration of oxygen is greater than the starting concentration of oxygen / 2
    while(ammoniaCurrent > (ammoniaStart / 2) || reactionRate > 0.04){
        //Calculate the reaction rate using equation 1: reactionRate = k*current concentration of NH3*(pow(current concentration of O2, 2));
        reactionRate = k*ammoniaCurrent*(pow(oxygenCurrent, 2));
        printf("reaction rate  = %f\n",reactionRate);
        //Calculate the current concentration of N2 by rearranging equation 2: current concentration of N2 = reactionRate*2*time;
        nitrogenCurrent = nitrogenCurrent + reactionRate*2*(time-0.38);
        //Calculate the current concentration of water by rearranging equation 2: current concentration of water = reactionRate*6*time;
        waterCurrent = waterCurrent + reactionRate*6*(time-0.38);
        //Add the current concentration of water to waterCurrent
        waterProduced = waterProduced + waterCurrent;
        //Calculate the current concentration of NH3 by rearranging equation 2: current concentration of NH3 = reactionRate*4*time*-1;
        printf("ammoniaCurrent = %f - %f\n",ammoniaCurrent, (reactionRate*4*(time-0.38)));
        ammoniaCurrent = ammoniaCurrent - (reactionRate*4*(time-0.38));
        printf("ammoniaCurrent = %f\n",ammoniaCurrent);
        //printf("%f now, %f then\n",ammoniaCurrent, ammoniaStart);
        //Calculate the current concentration of O2 by rearranging equation 2: current concentration of O2 = reactionRate*3*time*-1;
        oxygenCurrent = oxygenCurrent - (reactionRate*3*(time-0.38));
        //Else, print “Reaction has not passed 50% completion”.
        printf("Reaction has not passed 50%% completion\n");
        //Add 1 to i
        i++;
        //Increment time by 0.01 seconds
        time = time + 0.01;
        printf("time = %f\n",time);
    }
    //Print "Concentration of ammonia after 0.38s = %f mol/L",current concentration of NH3 = reactionRate*4*0.38*-1
    printf("Concentration of ammonia after 0.38s = %f mol/L\n",(ammoniaStart - (k*ammoniaStart*(pow(oxygenStart,2))*0.38*4)));
    //Print "Average concentration of water after %fs = %f mol/L",t, waterCurrent/i
    waterCurrent = waterCurrent / i;
    printf("Average concentration of water after %f s = %f mol/L\n",time, waterCurrent);
    //Print "%fs required for rate to drop below 0.040 mol/(L*s)"
    printf("%fs required for rate to drop below 0.040 mol/(L*s)\n",time);
    //Print "Concentration of nitrogen gas after %fs = current concentration of N2 mol/L"
    printf("Concentration of nitrogen gas after %fs = %f mol/L\n",time,nitrogenCurrent);
    //Print "Average concentration of water after %fs = concentration of water mol/L"
    printf("Average concentration of water after %fs = %f mol/L\n",time,waterCurrent);
    //Print “Reaction has passed 50% completion”.
    printf("Reaction has passed 50%% completion\n");
    //Missing: when to print that the reaction has not passed 50% completion, using nested while loops (check with someone ASAP for this one)???
}
```

When I input the required values, I get the resulting output:

Concentration of ammonia after 0.38s = 1.688096 mol/L

Average concentration of water after 0.660000 s = 0.068756 mol/L

0.660000s required for rate to drop below 0.040 mol/(L*s)

Concentration of nitrogen gas after 0.660000s = 0.641721 mol/L

Average concentration of water after 0.660000s = 0.068756 mol/L

Reaction has passed 50% completion

What is causing it to stop so quickly?

Comment: Please [edit] and show the exact input you use.

Comment: You seem to use `reactionRate` in the `while` condition without ever initializing it. So it may contain random data.

Comment: As a general tip, consider using whitespace to break of logical sections of code.  It will significantly help with readability.

Comment: As a suggestion, comments like ```//Add 1 to i``` add nothing useful, it's clear what ```i++;``` does. A general guideline: the code itself should document **what** is happening, short comments should document **why**.

Comment: Compiling this with `-O2 -Wall -Wextra` warns me about _3_ uninitialized variables: reactionRate, waterCurrent and nitrogenCurrent. 
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o5451sza3

Comment: Probably not a problem, but I'd rather use `double`s than `float`s. usually `float`s dont offer any benefit nowadays

Comment: @sj95126, when you're a complete beginner you're not going to know that `i++` being the same as `i = i + 1` is obvious. In other words, at this stage of learning, trying to get the commenting right really shouldn't be the focus - it's genuinely impossible as a beginner.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The variables `reactionRate`, `nitrogenCurrent`, `waterCurrent` and `waterProduced` are never initialized. Their initial value is therefore undetermined and they possibly contain an undetermined seemingly random value.

Initialize them to 0 before using them.

Change the first lines of `main` to this:

```
int main() {

  float ammoniaStart, oxygenStart, ammoniaCurrent, oxygenCurrent;

  // >>>> initialize those variables to zero
  float waterCurrent = 0, waterProduced = 0, reactionRate = 0, nitrogenCurrent = 0;
```

With these changes you get the expected output.

**Bonus**

Rewritten code without pointless commens and using `double`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  //Define value of k, starting concentration of NH3,starting 
  // concentration of O2,current concentration of NH3,current
  // concentration of O2, current concentration of N2, current
  // concentration of water, waterProduced, reactionRate and time
  // as doubles; initialize k and time, since k is a constant and
  // t has a fixed starting time

  double ammoniaStart, oxygenStart, ammoniaCurrent, oxygenCurrent;

  // >>>> initialize those variables to zero
  double waterCurrent = 0, waterProduced = 0, reactionRate = 0, nitrogenCurrent = 0;

  double k = 1.14 * pow(10, -2);
  printf("k = %f\n", k);
  double time = 0.38;

  int i = 0;
  //Scan in the starting concentrations of O2 and NH3
  printf("Enter initial ammonia & oxygen concentrations:");
  scanf("%lf %lf", &ammoniaStart, &oxygenStart);

  ammoniaCurrent = ammoniaStart;
  oxygenCurrent = oxygenStart;

  printf("ammoniaCurrent = %f, oxygenCurrent = %f\n", ammoniaCurrent, oxygenCurrent);

  // while the concentration of NH3 is greater than the starting concentration
  // of NH3 / 2 OR while the concentration of oxygen is greater than the starting concentration of oxygen / 2

  while (ammoniaCurrent > (ammoniaStart / 2) || reactionRate > 0.04) {
    //Calculate the reaction rate using equation 1: reactionRate = k*current concentration of NH3*(pow(current concentration of O2, 2));
    reactionRate = k * ammoniaCurrent * (pow(oxygenCurrent, 2));
    printf("reaction rate  = %f\n", reactionRate);
    
    //Calculate the current concentration of N2 by rearranging equation 2: current concentration of N2 = reactionRate*2*time;
    nitrogenCurrent = nitrogenCurrent + reactionRate * 2 * (time - 0.38);

    //Calculate the current concentration of water by rearranging equation 2: current concentration of water = reactionRate*6*time;
    waterCurrent = waterCurrent + reactionRate * 6 * (time - 0.38);

    waterProduced = waterProduced + waterCurrent;
    //Calculate the current concentration of NH3 by rearranging equation 2: current concentration of NH3 = reactionRate*4*time*-1;
    printf("ammoniaCurrent = %f - %f\n", ammoniaCurrent, (reactionRate * 4 * (time - 0.38)));

    ammoniaCurrent = ammoniaCurrent - (reactionRate * 4 * (time - 0.38));
    printf("ammoniaCurrent = %f\n", ammoniaCurrent);
    
    //printf("%f now, %f then\n",ammoniaCurrent, ammoniaStart);
    //Calculate the current concentration of O2 by rearranging equation 2: current concentration of O2 = reactionRate*3*time*-1;
    oxygenCurrent = oxygenCurrent - (reactionRate * 3 * (time - 0.38));
    

    printf("Reaction has not passed 50%% completion\n");
    i++;
    time = time + 0.01;
    printf("time = %f\n", time);
  }

  printf("Concentration of ammonia after 0.38s = %f mol/L\n", (ammoniaStart - (k * ammoniaStart * (pow(oxygenStart, 2)) * 0.38 * 4)));
  waterCurrent = waterCurrent / i;

  printf("Average concentration of water after %f s = %f mol/L\n", time, waterCurrent);

  //Print "%fs required for rate to drop below 0.040 mol/(L*s)"
  printf("%fs required for rate to drop below 0.040 mol/(L*s)\n", time);
  printf("Concentration of nitrogen gas after %fs = %f mol/L\n", time, nitrogenCurrent);
  printf("Average concentration of water after %fs = %f mol/L\n", time, waterCurrent);
  printf("Reaction has passed 50%% completion\n");

  //Missing: when to print that the reaction has not passed 50% completion, using nested while loops (check with someone ASAP for this one)???
}
```

Comment: This sort of question comes up all the time. There must be an uninitialized variables canonical answer by now.